# Accessing the Resource by different Task

Tags: microcontroller, os

I have a simple question on Accessing the resources in the OS concept(freeRtos). If one low priority task is running and using the resource(preemptive scheduling) .

**Resource for LPT(low priority Task) and HPT(High Priority Task)**

```
extern uint8 x;
void func(void)
{ 
  uint8 y = 10 
  if((x - y))
  {

      //Some Code
      x = -1;
      y++; //line 7
  }
 }
```

**Resource for HPT(High Priority Task) which will fun every 5 ms**

```
  if(cond)
  {
       func();
  }
```

if the Low Priority Task executing the line number 7, at that time higher priority task executed. Then what could be the value of x?. This is an example. My question is whether after executing the line number 7 by LPT, then HPT in running sate the value of x and y will be the same what LPT changed?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, A lot depends on the system you are using but it boils down to weather the instructions are "atomic" in nature. If the instruction is atomic it means it cannot be interrupted until it is complete. If the instruction is not atomic then the behavior on the value of x becomes non-deterministic so the value of X becomes "who knows" for this type of situation you can implemented taskEnterCritical and taskExitCritical which are used to make section of the code atomic in nature. Also, you can considere the use of semaphore and/or mutexes to implement mutually exclusive access to a resource.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if I am using a critical section or any lock, if LPT is executing the Line 7, at that time HPT will be in running state, then it won't enter the Lock Section or critical section, unless LPT unlock it or exit the critical section?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with your particular system, but I have seen how these types of systems work in general.  Basically, you have an interrupt that fires every so often, usually from a timer, and the ISR decides whether to simply return-from-interrupt to the task that it interrupted or whether to switch stacks and then return-from-interrupt, thus switching tasks.

So in terms of your situation, you would handle it as if func() was called from both the main loop and an ISR, which is usually a no-no because of the issue that you described.  It can be done, but it's very easy to mess things up if you don't do it right.

If func() must be done immediately, then I would look for a way to block the task-switch interrupt from firing until it's done.  It's kind of a hack on the OS to do that, but it would solve the problem.  Or if it can be delayed, I would set a flag to have it done later, and then call it exclusively from one task that won't preempt itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming line #7 refers to the line x = -1; since if I count seven lines down from the top I come to a blank line above //Some code.

If the base level (low priority) is executing that line of code, and it is interrupted by the ISR which then executes, what happens to x?  Nothing unexpected, since both execution threads are setting the variable to -1.  On most CPUs, doing this will need two instructions: setting a register to -1, and then storing it to memory.  If the interrupt occurs before the first or second instruction, x is set to -1 by the ISR and then set to -1 right after the ISR returns.  If the interrupt occurs after the second instruction, then the base level has already set x to -1, and the ISR will do so again.

The more interesting case is the line y++;

Assuming a CPU that has no increment memory instruction, this will typically take three instructions: load a register from memory, increment the register, and store back to memory.

We have four cases: interrupt before the first instruction, interrupt after the first instruction (load), interrupt after the second instruction (increment), and interrupt after the third instruction (store).

In the case where the interrupt occurs before the first instruction, or after the third one, it is pretty clear that y will be increment twice, going from 10 to 12.  However in the other two cases, y only gets incremented once.

Here is the case when the interrupt occurs first (same thing if it occurs last):

```
(int)
    ldr y   10
    inc     11
    str y   11
(rti)
ldr y       11
inc         12
str y       12
```

In my simple notation, ldr, inc, and str mean load register, increment register, and store register; y is some memory address, and (int) and (rti) indicate where the interrupt occurs and the return from interrupt.

However here is what happens when the interrupt occurs after the first instruction:

```
ldr y       10
(int)
    ldr y   10
    inc     11
    str y   11
(rti)
inc         11      
str y       11
```

So y only gets incremented once.  Same thing when the interrupt occurs after the increment.

So even though y++ is a single operation in C, it is not an "atomic" operation -- it takes multiple machine instructions to execute it.  To safely guard against this sort of thing, where a volatile variable can be accessed from either an ISR or the base level at the same time, the code needs to be enclosed in a critical region.  This can be done by disabling interrupts before the line(s) of code, and enabling them again afterwards.

Note that this is an argument for not using the same function from both the base level and interrupt level, since you generally would not want to disable and re-enable interrupts inside a function called by an ISR.